# Is this a OOP in Javascript? How to initialize it internally?

Tags: javascript

I am using the below Javascript structure but I don't know what do they call this structure? Also, I am unable to initialize variables this way:

```
(object={}).init();
```

Structure:

```
var object=(

    function(){

        function local(){}

        return {
            global: function(){}
        }

    }()
);
```

Does it consider as OOP in Javscript? A correct approach?

Thank you!

Comment: `(object={}).init();` doesn't make sense. It's same as doing this: `object={};object.init();` But new "empty" objects have no `init` member function ..

Answer (score 1):

That's called (a variation) of a **Module Pattern**.

It has to do with OOP in the sense that it deals with something that is normally is one of the attributes of OOP - code encapsulation and (to a much lesser extent) code organization and reuse.

See [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

As for this:

`(object={}).init();`

that's just ugly unreadable code that should not be written like this. And it will fail, since there is not `init` method on the object.

Answer (score 0):

This could be called a self invoking function or an immediately invoked function.

This approach can be used in OOP and can be used as an approach to the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Object(){
   this.variable = 123;
   this.init = function(){ alert(this.variable);  };
}
var obj = new Object();
obj.init();
```